# How to recognize cpu brand name in c/assembler by cpuid instruction

Tags: c, assembly, cpuid

I have no idea how should this program work, i found some codes but i don't understand them, if somebody here was so kind and had program like this could you explain it to me?

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <string.h>
int main()
{
char name[13];
 __asm
{
XOR EAX,EAX
CPUID
MOV dword ptr [name], EBX
MOV dword ptr [name+4], EDX
MOV dword ptr [name+8], ECX
 }
name[12]=0;
printf("Procesor: %s\n", name);
getchar();
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `cpuid` instruction tells you various things about the CPU depending on the content of the `eax` register. When `eax` contains zero, the registers `ebx`, `edx`, and `ecx` contain a string describing the processor's vendor. The code you have pulls the string from the registers and prints it out.

Read [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPUID) for further details on `cpuid`.